# Executable out of script containing serial_for_url

Tags: python, py2exe, pyserial, canopy

I have developed a python script for making a serial communication to a digital pump. I now need to make an executable out of it. However even though it works perfectly well when running it with python and py2exe does produce the .exe properly when I run the executable the following error occurs:

```
File: pump_model.pyc in line 96 in connect_new
File: serial\__init__.pyc in line 71 in serial_for_url
ValueError: invalid URL protocol 'loop' not known
```

The relevant piece of my code is the following:
    # New serial connection
    def connect_new(self, port_name):
        """Function for configuring a new serial connection."""

```
    try:
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port = port_name,\
                baudrate = 9600,\
                parity = 'N',\
                stopbits = 1,\
                bytesize = 8,\
                timeout = self.timeout_time)
    except serial.SerialException:
        self.ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://',\
              timeout = self.timeout_time) # This line BLOWS!
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()[0]

    finally:
        self.initialize_pump()
```

I should note that the application was written in OSX and was tested on Windows with the Canopy Python Distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It seems that for some reason the 'loop://' arguement can't be recognised after the .exe production.

I figured out by studying the pyserial/**init**.py script that when issuing the command serial.serial_for_url(‘loop://') you essentially call:
sys.modules['serial.urlhandler.protocol_loop’].Serial(“loop://“)

So you have to first import the serial.urlhandler.protocol_loop 
and then issue that command in place of the one malfunctioning.
So you can now type:

```
__import__('serial.urlhandler.protocol_loop')
sys.modules[‘serial.urlhandler.protocol_loop’].Serial("loop://")
```

After this minor workaround it worked fine.

Comment: Glad you found it! Please mark this (your own answer) as accepted so it will be clear that the question has been answered. (SO standard etiquette)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem with "socket://" rather than "loop://"

I wasn't able to get the accepted answer to work however the following seems to succeed:

1) Add an explicit import of the offending urlhandler.* module

```
import serial

# explicit import for py2exe - to fix "socket://" url issue
import serial.urlhandler.protocol_socket 

# explicit import for py2exe - to fix "loop://" url issue (OP's particular prob)
import serial.urlhandler.protocol_loop

# use serial_for_url in normal manner
self._serial = serial.serial_for_url('socket://192.168.1.99:12000')
```

2) Generate a setup script for py2exe (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/) -- I've installed py2exe to a virtualenv:

```
path\to\env\Scripts\python.exe -m py2exe myscript.py -W mysetup.py
```

3) edit mysetup.py to include option

```
zipfile="library.zip" # default generated value is None
```

(see also http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions)

3) build it:

```
path\to\env\Scripts\python.exe mysetup.py py2exe
```

4) run it

```
dist\myscript.exe
```